# Java Two List<?> Using Iterator remove element from one?

Tags: java

i have Two list`,List<String> and List<Item>.`

```
public class Item {
    private String name;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**My Code::**

```
public class Twolist {

    List<Item> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();


    public Twolist() {

        Item item = new Item();
        item.setName("itemname1");
        list1.add(item);

        item = new Item();
        item.setName("itemname2");
        list1.add(item);

        item = new Item();
        item.setName("itemname3");
        list1.add(item);

        item = new Item();
        item.setName("itemname4");
        list1.add(item);

        item = new Item();
        item.setName("itemname5");
        list1.add(item);

        item = new Item();
        item.setName("itemname6");
        list1.add(item);

        item = new Item();
        item.setName("itemname7");
        list1.add(item);

        item = new Item();
        item.setName("itemname8");
        list1.add(item);

        // list 2 start here

        list2.add("itemname2");
        list2.add("itemname4");
        list2.add("itemname6");
        list2.add("itemname8");

        Iterator<Item> it1 = list1.iterator();

        while (it1.hasNext()) {
            Item item2 = (Item) it1.next();
            System.out.println(item2.getName());


            for (int i = 0; i < list2.size(); i++) {
                String str = list2.get(i);

                if (item2.equals(str)) {

                } else {
                    it1.remove();
                }
            }

        }

        System.out.println(list1.size());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Twolist();
    }
```

**Error::**

```
itemname1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.remove(ArrayList.java:804)
    at com.samir.CollectionP.Twolist.<init>(Twolist.java:67)
    at com.samir.CollectionP.Twolist.main(Twolist.java:78)
```

if name in `List<Item>` is equals `List<String>`is same then remove element from `List<Item>`. how can i remove element from `List<Item>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to remove data not in common in the 2 lists, try:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
  String s1 = list1.get(i).getName();
  System.out.println(s1);
  boolean found = false;
  for (int j = 0; j < list2.size(); j++) {
    String s2 = list2.get(j);
    if(s1.equals(s2)){
      found = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if(!found){
    list1.remove(i);
    i--;
  }
}
```

you need to use the `boolean found` in order not to delete all the elements.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you have multiple problems, so here is a possible solution (if you want to remove the elements of list2 from list1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
  String s1 = list1.get(i).getName();
  System.out.println(s1);
  for (int j = 0; j < list2.size(); j++) {
    String s2 = list2.get(j);
    if(s1.equals(s2)){
      list1.remove(i);
      i--;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: but i need to remove data which are not common and when i use  `if(!s1.equals(s2))` it cant works ?

Comment: no, this will remove all the elements in the list1.
check my new answer

Answer (score 1):

In your internal `for` loop you are calling `it1.remove();` (eventually) multiple times, for a single call to `it1.next()` right at the beginning on `while` loop.
You can not call `it1.remove();` multiple times for a single `it1.next()`

the [javadocs for `Iterator.remove()` expalins the details](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29)

```
class Item { String name; }

class SOF {

    static List<Item> list1 = new ArrayList();
    static List<String> list2 = new ArrayList();

    static {
        Iterator<Item> i = list1.iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            if (!exists(i.next().name)) {
                i.remove();
            }
        }
    }

    static boolean exists(String s) {
        for (String s2: list2) {
            if (s2.equals(s2))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: then how to remove element from List<Item>  ?

Comment: Every time after `remove()` call `hasNext()` and if there is something call `next()` In your case, probably you wnat to `break` the internal loop once you remove the element

Comment: You have to explain better in the question what do you actually want to happen... what is the puropse of you cdoe

Comment: i have two list ,and List<Item> have Item object.and Item class have String name field.Now second List<String> and there are name in list.so i want check which name is common in two list and remove uncommon name from List<Item> i mean remove item object see my code...

Answer (score 1):

The provided solution will work, BUT:

I think a `HashMap<String, Item> list1` will be a better datatype. It is definitive faster than a `List`.